# How do I maintain the file order in Windows Explorer when drag and dropping files into wpf/C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-3.0, drag-and-drop

In my application the user can drag and drop files from windows explorer onto a listbox in my application. This all works excellent however when dragging multiple files, depending which file the user clicks in windows explorer to begin dragging, the order the files passed will differ when calling:

```
e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)
```

How do I receive the files in the same order as they are displayed in windows explorer?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order you receive them is the order in which they were selected. I encountered this problem once before and as far as I was able to tell you cannot get them in Explorer's sort order.

Therefore your code should assume the user selected them in that order for a reason.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am finding the case to be the opposite however in that the user is expecting the files to be in the order they appear when being dragged from windows explorer.

Comment: I feel for these users, and it is why I sought out the solution. However, Windows has to assume the user selected them in a given order for a reason, hence you should as well. It isn't great, but it is one of the areas where Windows isn't trying to think for you (which MS is often slammed for in other areas).

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for your help.

Comment: My "solution" was to provide modifier-keys which turned on the most common sorts (name, date, type). I don't believe those were ever used in production by my users though.

Comment: This sounds like observed behavior instead of something Explorer is doing by contract. If that's the case, you should at least comment you code to that effect in case some future version of Explorer (or past version you haven't tested) changes behavior and breaks your code's assumptions. I realize that relying on 'current behavior' sometimes needs to be done, but just be sure you understand that and have at least considered the ramifications of a change in that behavior. And be prepared for your application to be the anonymized subject of some future "The Old New Thing" article.

Comment: @Michael Burr: good point, I guess `CF_HDROP` (et al) never specify the order you would get the files. I think in terms of "expectations" one would expect if you select B, A, D, then C, you would get them in that order. Especially considering the methods used to do drag/drop (of course this assumes Explorer uses a similar sequence) have a proscribed sequence.

Comment: In response to ya'll saying "respect the order the user chose": Windows itself is not respecting it - that is the issue. The user selects file1,file2,file3, etc. When dropped onto something, the order ends up being file4,file5,file6,file1,file1,file2,file3.

Comment: @Matt: which version of Windows?

Comment: @sixlettervariables I've seen it in Win 95, XP and Vista

Comment: @Matt: I've not seen that behavior, at least on XP and 7. Not that I don't believe you; it does some weird things from time to time.

Answer (score 9):

If you shift-select a bunch of files from 0000 to 0010 and then drag them into an application (say video files and drag them into VLC).
Explorer will feed the list not in the order you selected the items but from the item you left-click-n-dragged from.

Click on 0000 and they will show up in number order.
Click on 0003 and they will show up from 0003 to 0010 and then 0001 and 0002

So the correct way to "drag n drop" is to always drag from the top.

Comment: Does anyone know where this counter-intuitive logic came from? Was there a beneficial reason, or simply a weird quirk that nobody ever bothered to fix?